# Instantiate child class without knowing the type

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have the following setup:

```
public abstract class HyperComplexNumber {
    public HyperComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary) {
        Real = real;
        Imaginary = imaginary;
    }

    public double Real;
    public double Imaginary;

    public static HyperComplexNumber operator+(HyperComplexNumber left, HyperComplexNumber right)
    {
        return new HyperComplexNumber(left.Real + right.Real, left.Imaginary + right.Imaginary);
    }
}

public class ComplexNumber : HyperComplexNumber {
     // Some code here
}

public class SplitComplexNumber : HyperComplexNumber {
     // Some code here
}

public class DualNumber : HyperComplexNumber {
     // Some code here
}
```

Now the problem is, that inside the operator+ definition, it's not possible the instantiate `HyperComplexNumber` (since it's abstract). I see multiple ways to solve this, but none of them seems good enough.

One way is to implement the operator+ in each child class separately, but this just leads to redundant code, since all of the child classes would essentially have the same code in the operator definition.

Another way could be to use reflection to instantiate the child class, but I heard that using reflection is usually a code smell. So that's why I'm asking this question: what would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: What if `left` is `ComplexNumber` and `right` is `DualNumber`? Is that operation defined for different child classes?

Comment: Continuing Evk's comment, if it is defined, then in that case, what concrete class do you expect to be instantiated?

Comment: @Evk No, it's not defined in that case, that should throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would *remove* operator + from the base abstract class, because it:

1. Might be used incorrectly (when operands are of different subtypes, like `ComplexNumber` and `DualNumber`).
2. Has fixed return type of base `HyperComplexNumber`, so it's not convenient to use anyway. For example, if I have `ComplexNumber a` and `ComplexNumber b`, I'd expect in `c = a + b` for `c` to be of type `ComplexNumber` at compile time, without any explicit casting. Now variable `c` will *always* be `HyperComplexNumber` (even though actual type might be `ComplexNumber`).

So I'd remove this operator from base class and then add it to every subclass. Yes it's a bit of code duplication, but in this case it's justified, because now those operators are actually useful and work as you would expect.

You can reduce code duplication a bit with something like:

```
public abstract class HyperComplexNumber {
    public HyperComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary) {
        Real = real;
        Imaginary = imaginary;
    }

    public double Real;
    public double Imaginary;

    protected static (double real, double im) Add(HyperComplexNumber left, HyperComplexNumber right) {
        return (left.Real + right.Real, left.Imaginary + right.Imaginary);
    }
}

public class ComplexNumber : HyperComplexNumber {
    public ComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary) : base(real, imaginary) {
    }

    public static ComplexNumber operator +(ComplexNumber left, ComplexNumber right) {
        var (real, im) = Add(left, right);
        return new ComplexNumber(real, im);
    }
}
```

Though obviously in this case it doesn't reduce much.

Answer (score 0):

For now I see 2 solutions if you do not create overrides for child types:

## First — only extension methods

**Create constructor without parameters and make properties init-only** (if you don't want to change them after object creation):

```
public HyperComplexNumber()
{
}

public double Real { get; init; }
public double Imaginary { get; init; }
```

**Create type that represents sum of complex numbers of different types** (if you want to be able to sum different types):

```
public class SumOfDifferentNumbers : HyperComplexNumber
{
    // Some code here
}
```

**Create 2 extension methods:**

```
public static class HyperComplexNumberExtensions
{
    public static TNumber Sum<TNumber>(this TNumber left, TNumber right)
        where TNumber : HyperComplexNumber, new()
    {
        return new TNumber
        {
            Real = left.Real + right.Real,
            Imaginary = left.Imaginary + right.Imaginary
        };
    }

    // If you want to sum different types
    public static TResult Sum<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(this TFirst left, TSecond right)
        where TFirst : HyperComplexNumber
        where TSecond : HyperComplexNumber
        where TResult : HyperComplexNumber, new()
    {
        return new TResult
        {
            Real = left.Real + right.Real,
            Imaginary = left.Imaginary + right.Imaginary
        };
    }
}
```

**And use them like this:**

```
var left = new ComplexNumber
{
    Real = 1,
    Imaginary = 2
};

var right = new ComplexNumber
{
    Real = 1,
    Imaginary = 2
};

var sum1 = left.Sum(right);

var rightOfOtherType = new DualNumber
{
    Real = 1,
    Imaginary = 2
};

var sum2 = left.Sum<ComplexNumber, DualNumber, SumOfDifferentNumbers>(rightOfOtherType);
```

## Second — with operator

**Do all steps from the first solution**.

**Add the following code to the** `HyperComplexNumberExtensions` (if you want to be able to sum different types):

```
public static readonly MethodInfo[] AllSumMethods =
    typeof(HyperComplexNumberExtensions)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(m => m.Name == nameof(HyperComplexNumberExtensions.Sum))
        .ToArray()
```

**Define sum operator in** `HyperComplexNumber` like this:

```
public static HyperComplexNumber operator +(HyperComplexNumber left, HyperComplexNumber right)
{
    MethodInfo sumMethod;
    MethodInfo genericImplementation;
    if (left.GetType() == right.GetType())
    {
        sumMethod = HyperComplexNumberExtensions.AllSumMethods.First(m => m.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1);
        genericImplementation = sumMethod.MakeGenericMethod(left.GetType());
    }
    else
    {
        sumMethod = HyperComplexNumberExtensions.AllSumMethods.First(m => m.GetGenericArguments().Length == 3);
        genericImplementation = sumMethod.MakeGenericMethod(
            left.GetType(), 
            right.GetType(), 
            typeof(SumOfDifferentNumbers));
    }
    return (HyperComplexNumber)genericImplementation.Invoke(null, new[] { left, right });
}
```

**And use it like this** (it is assumed that before this is the code from the previous example):

```
var rightOfOtherType = new DualNumber
{
    Real = 1,
    Imaginary = 2
};

sum1 = (ComplexNumber)(left + right);
sum2 = (SumOfDifferentNumbers)(left + rightOfOtherType);
```

## Remarks

You can define sum of different types without third generic parameter and return concrete type, for example `SumOfDifferentNumber`.

If you want to sum only same types, you can throw exception on non-equality of types in sum operator.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your problem is instantiation of an abstract class. I agree with @EvK that operator overloading is not the solution you should be looking to implement. However, if you must, for whatever reasons, try this:

```
public static HyperComplexNumber operator+(HyperComplexNumber left, HyperComplexNumber right)
{
    var sumValue = (HyperComplexNumber) left.MemberWiseClone();
    sumValue.Real += right.Real;
    sumValue.Imaginary+= right.Imaginary;
    return sumValue;
}
```

But standard caveats apply. These include that you have only these two values, they are primitive etc etc. I hope you get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done it in the past. I used a generic specification for a future class. Below `TComplex` is to specified by the deriving classes as their own, but it can be used in the base class to describe those future classes.

An example implementation of complex and dual numbers is below with algebra, formatting, and some other goodies.

#### Complex numeric type usage

The numeric types define algebra style operators and most call functions on the common base class. What is different between the specific complex types are the rules of multiplication which are specialized with the `Product(TComplex other)` method.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new ComplexNumber(1.0, -5.0);
        var b = new ComplexNumber(1.0, +5.0);

        Console.WriteLine($"a = {a}, {a.GetType().Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"b = {b}, {b.GetType().Name}");
        //a = 1-5i, ComplexNumber
        //b = 1+5i, ComplexNumber

        Console.WriteLine($"a + b = {a + b}");
        Console.WriteLine($"a - b = {a - b}");
        Console.WriteLine($"a * b = {a * b}");
        // a + b = 2
        // a - b = -10i
        // a * b = 26

        var c = 2.0 * a + 3.0 * b;
        Console.WriteLine($"c = {c}, {c.GetType().Name}");
        // c = 5+5i, ComplexNumber

        var p = new DualNumber(1.0, -5.0);
        var q = new DualNumber(1.0, +5.0);

        Console.WriteLine($"p = {p}, {p.GetType().Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"q = {q}, {q.GetType().Name}");
        //p = 1 - 5ε, DualNumber
        //q = 1 + 5ε, DualNumber

        Console.WriteLine($"p + q = {p + q}");
        Console.WriteLine($"p - q = {p - q}");
        Console.WriteLine($"p * q = {p * q}");
        // p + q = 2
        // p - q = -10ε
        // p * q = 1
    }

}
```

#### Complex numeric type implementation

Most of the common code is defined in the base class. Each specialized complex type defines its own constructors, random initialization, own equality, the symbol for non-real component, rule for multiplication, and implicit/explicit conversions to and from `double`.

```
public abstract class HyperComplexNumber<TComplex>
where TComplex : HyperComplexNumber<TComplex>, new()
{
    protected static readonly Random rng = new Random();

    protected HyperComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary)
    {
        Real = real;
        Imaginary = imaginary;
    }

    public double Real { get; private set; }
    public double Imaginary { get; private set;  }
    public abstract string Symbol { get; }
    public TComplex Scale(double factor)
    {
        var t = new TComplex
        {
            Real = factor * Real,
            Imaginary = factor * Imaginary
        };
        return t;
    }
    public TComplex Add(TComplex other)
    {
        var t = new TComplex
        {
            Real = Real + other.Real,
            Imaginary = Imaginary + other.Imaginary
        };
        return t;
    }
    public TComplex Subtract(TComplex other)
    {
        var t = new TComplex
        {
            Real = Real - other.Real,
            Imaginary = Imaginary - other.Imaginary
        };
        return t;
    }
    public abstract TComplex Product(TComplex other);

    #region Operators
    public static TComplex operator +(HyperComplexNumber<TComplex> rhs) => (TComplex)rhs;
    public static TComplex operator -(HyperComplexNumber<TComplex> rhs) => rhs.Scale(-1);
    public static TComplex operator +(HyperComplexNumber<TComplex> lhs, TComplex rhs) => lhs.Add(rhs);
    public static TComplex operator -(HyperComplexNumber<TComplex> lhs, TComplex rhs) => lhs.Subtract(rhs);
    public static TComplex operator *(double factor, HyperComplexNumber<TComplex> lhs) => lhs.Scale(factor);
    public static TComplex operator *(HyperComplexNumber<TComplex> lhs, double factor) => lhs.Scale(factor);
    public static TComplex operator /(HyperComplexNumber<TComplex> lhs, double divider) => lhs.Scale(1/divider);
    public static TComplex operator *(HyperComplexNumber<TComplex> lhs, TComplex rhs) => lhs.Product(rhs);
    #endregion


    #region IEquatable Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Equality overrides from <see cref="System.Object"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to compare this with</param>
    /// <returns>False if object is a different type, otherwise it calls <code>Equals(HyperComplexNumber)</code></returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is HyperComplexNumber<TComplex> item)
        {
            return Equals(item);
        }
        return false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for equality among <see cref="HyperComplexNumber"/> classes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if equal</returns>
    public bool Equals(HyperComplexNumber<TComplex> other)
    {
        return Real.Equals(other.Real)
            && Imaginary.Equals(other.Imaginary);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the hash code for the <see cref="HyperComplexNumber"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The int hash value</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hc = -1817952719;
            hc = (-1521134295) * hc + Real.GetHashCode();
            hc = (-1521134295) * hc + Imaginary.GetHashCode();
            return hc;
        }
    }

    #endregion


    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (Real == 0 && Imaginary == 0) return "0";
        string rPart = string.Empty, iPart = string.Empty, sign = string.Empty;
        if (Real != 0.0)
        {
            rPart = Real.ToString(format, formatProvider);
        }
        if (Imaginary != 0.0)
        {
            if (Imaginary < 0)
            {
                sign = "-";
            }
            else if (Real != 0)
            {
                sign = "+";
            }
            iPart = $"{Math.Abs(Imaginary).ToString(format, formatProvider)}{Symbol}";
        }
        return $"{rPart}{sign}{iPart}";
    }

    public string ToString(string formatting)
        => ToString(formatting, null);
    public override string ToString()
        => ToString("g");

}

public sealed class ComplexNumber : 
    HyperComplexNumber<ComplexNumber>,
    IEquatable<ComplexNumber>
{
    public ComplexNumber() : this(0, 0) { }
    public ComplexNumber(double real) : this(real, 0) { }
    public ComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary) : base(real, imaginary) { }
    public static ComplexNumber Random() => new ComplexNumber(rng.NextDouble(), rng.NextDouble());
    public static implicit operator ComplexNumber(double real) => new ComplexNumber(real);
    public static explicit operator double(ComplexNumber number) => number.Real;
    public override string Symbol => "i";
    public override ComplexNumber Product(ComplexNumber other)
        => new ComplexNumber(
            Real * other.Real - Imaginary * other.Imaginary,
            Real * other.Imaginary + Imaginary * other.Real);
    public bool Equals(ComplexNumber other)
        => base.Equals(other);
}

public sealed class DualNumber : 
    HyperComplexNumber<DualNumber>,
    IEquatable<DualNumber>
{
    public DualNumber() : this(0, 0) { }
    public DualNumber(double real) : this(real, 0) { }
    public DualNumber(double real, double imaginary) : base(real, imaginary) { }
    public static DualNumber Random() => new DualNumber(rng.NextDouble(), rng.NextDouble());
    public static implicit operator DualNumber(double real) => new DualNumber(real);
    public static explicit operator double(DualNumber number) => number.Real;
    public override string Symbol => "ε";
    public override DualNumber Product(DualNumber other)
        => new DualNumber(
            Real * other.Real,
            Real * other.Imaginary + Imaginary * other.Real);

    public bool Equals(DualNumber other)
        => base.Equals(other);
}
```

PS. I recommend using the new `record` types which are like classes, but immutable and can auto-equate by value, something I have not implemented above.